# Bundle.entry.fullUrl is invalid when posting a fhir bundle

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to post a bundle with a patient and observation resource, this is the json i'm trying to post

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "bundle-transaction",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2014-08-18T01:43:30Z"
    },
    "type": "transaction",
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:05efabf0-4be2-4561-91ce-51548425acb9",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Patient",
                "active": true,
                "name": [
                    {
                        "use": "official",
                        "family": "Jones",
                        "given": "Indiana"
                    }
                ],
                "gender": "male",
                "birthDate": "1990-12-20"
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "url": "Patient"
            }
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:dd7885c2-cf0d-4d5f-981c-94c98df345ad",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "status": "final",
                "category": [
                    {
                        "coding": [
                            {
                                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/observation-category",
                                "code": "vital-signs",
                                "display": "Vital Signs"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "code": {
                    "coding": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://loinc.org",
                            "code": "29463-7",
                            "display": "Body Weight"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "subject": {
                    "type": "Patient",
                    "reference": "urn:uuid:05efabf0-4be2-4561-91ce-51548425acb9"
                },
                "effectiveDateTime": "2016-03-28",
                "valueQuantity": {
                    "value": 185,
                    "unit": "lbs",
                    "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
                    "code": "[lb_av]"
                }
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "url": "Observation"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

the problem is i'm getting **Bundle.entry.fullUrl is invalid** as a response, what could be the issue here i'm using a UUID as fullUrl and as I've seen in various tutorials it's a valid way to do things

I tried alot of things to solve this such as keeping only the uuid and removing the "urn:uuid" part with no result

Answer (score 2):

Your Bundle looks correct to me, and both the Firely as well as the HAPI public test servers accept it without problems. The example Bundle in the FHIR specification also shows the urn:uuid way of linking resources that do not have an identity yet as a good example of a transaction, see: http://hl7.org/fhir/bundle-transaction.json.html. Also the paragraph about resolving references in Bundles mentions resolving urns: http://hl7.org/fhir/bundle.html#references.

My guess is that the server you are using is not capable of this. You could try and replace the reference and the fullUrl of the Patient with an 'actual' url like `http://example.org/Patient/1` and see if the server wants to accept that. If it does, it should replace the reference with the newly created one just like when you had used urn:uuid. If not, reach out to the server's developers for assistance.